# Get data ordered by document Id descending in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from my Firestore db ordered by `documentId` in descending order. When I call:

```
firestore.collection("users")
    .orderBy(FieldPath.documentId(), Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {...});
```

I am getting error:

> FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index.

With a link to Firebase console for automatic index creation. Unfortunately the automatic creation doesn't seem to work in this case. When I click on Create Index I get a message:

> __name__ only indexes are not supported

For manual index creation, the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) only says about indexing by field name (not `documentId`). Does anyone know how to get data from Firestore ordered by `documentId` in descending order?

I know I can re-order data on client side, but ordering by id is such a natural task that I must be missing something. Thank you. I use:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.6.0'
```

Comment: how about read access in firestore?

Comment: Can you share your "rules" json? Maybe you need something like:

'".indexOn": ["documentId"]'

Comment: While testing, I have default Firestore access, i.e. allow read, write for everybody. @NicoT.: please would you send a link to a doc?

Comment: @zelig74 here is the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: @NicoT. Thank you, but this is doc for Realtime Database, not for Cloud Firestore.

Comment: For future searchers, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119208#answer-62678981) for a possible work around.

Answer (score 9):

As stated in the Firestore document [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), Cloud Firestore does not provide automatic ordering on the auto-generated docIDs.

> Important: Unlike "push IDs" in the Firebase Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore auto-generated IDs do not provide any automatic ordering. If you want to be able to order your documents by creation date, you should store a timestamp as a field in the documents.

Hence you can achieve ordering by adding an extra field ***createdDate*** and just setting it with [annotation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ServerTimestamp) @ServerTimestamp, declaring it before the class field in your user POJO like this.

```
@ServerTimestamp
Date createdDate;
```

Also you must ensure this field is null when the POJO is being written on Firestore, do not set any value to it before saving it on Firestore.

Comment: The reason that Firestore does not order auto-generated IDs led me to manualy call .orderBy(...). The problem is that ordering requires index whitch I don't know how to create on ID.

Comment: If I am understanding your query correctly then you still want to add the auto-generated Firestore ID as an index so as to order result based on it. There are **two** things here: 1.) Firebase team advises against using auto-generated ID at all for ordering the query results as they do not provide automatic ordering like RTDB push ID. 2.) You can only create document fields as a query index and ID is not part of the document. Also by default each doc field is indexed. Hence they are advising to add an extra field _createDate_ as above to order query result based on the document creation date.

Comment: Why are you talking about creation date? Author of question didn't say about chronological sorting his documents.

Comment: @EugeneGriaznov zelig74's desire to order by ID doesn't tell you he wants chronological sorting? Which order would you expect when sorting by ID?

Comment: @Parziphal, I expect chronologically random order when sort by ID.

Comment: @Eugene - That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer here is not correct.

From [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

> auto-generated IDs do not provide any automatic ordering.

Yes, because you don't know what the auto-generated ID will be. That does not mean the default sort order is not by id, in fact, another doc page says quite the opposite:

From [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data):

> By default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in
> ascending order by document ID. You can specify the sort order for
> your data using orderBy(), and you can limit the number of documents
> retrieved using limit().

So yes, you can sort in descending order by document id:

```js
.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'desc')
```

J

### Update Firebase 9

```
import { documentId } from 'firebase/firestore';
...

query(
  documentRef, 
  where(...), 
  orderBy(documentId, 'desc'), 
  limit(2)
);
```

Comment: How can you do this with the new v9 modules? I'm getting an error saying `FieldPath.documentId()` isnt a function

Comment: Have you actually tried it? By default, ordered by documentId in ascending order, and it doesn't require index. Try it DESC, it won't work without index. Even in 2024 ;)

Answer (score -3):

Use this to order in descending order based on id:

```
.collection("jobs")
.orderBy("", "desc")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws an error: "Error: Value for argument "fieldPath" is not a valid field path. Paths can't be empty..."