# How to get documents descending by DocumentID?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am encountering the issue [encountered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437291/get-data-ordered-by-document-id-descending-in-firestore). Because the other question (and answer) is missing the point of solving the problem, I am writing a new question.

```
orderBy(FieldPath.documentId(), 'desc')
```

The above query will fail with the following error message:

> The query requires an index. You can create it here:  ...

As described in the other question, it is impossible to create that index because of the following error message:

> __name__ only indexes are not supported

*Because the **opposite query** works fine*:

```
orderBy(FieldPath.documentId(), 'asc')
```

I am wondering why the **descending query** does not work. To me that does not really make a lot of sense, especially because this should be a very common use case.

It would be awesome if there is a solution to the above problem, i.e. if there is a way to create an index that makes `'desc'` work. However, I expect that it just is not a possibility and will therefore phrase a broader problem.

#### How do I really get my documents in descending order by the Document ID?

I could obviously do the `'asc'` query and then reverse my retrieved list.
But this **does not work** because I need to `limit()` the query. I cannot just pay for all the documents in a collection just to get a *descending order*.
*This way I **would get billed** for **all document reads in the collection** even if I **just wanted to get a single one** (the last one)*. [Here is a great article discussing potential consequences of this](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-spent-30k-usd-in-firebase-in-less-than-72-hours-307490bd24d) because it does **not scale**.

Do I really need to create a field called `id`, which contains the **exact same** `documentID`, just to create an index on it and then be able to query descendingly?
A potential collection could look like this:

```
"q":
 - id: "q"
"u":
 - id: "u"
"i":
 - id: "i"
"t":
 - id: "t"
"e":
 - id: "e"
"d":
 - id: "d"
"u":
 - id: "u"
"m":
 - id: "m"
"b":
 - id: "b"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to perform a descending query based on document ID.  Your alternative is to put the document ID in a field of the document, and use that for ordering.

Feel free to also [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for this, but it's not likely to happen in the near term.

Comment: Since this answer you guys have introduced the .limitToLast() method for queries. It's possible to do startAfter(lastDocSnap.id).limit(n) but endBefore(firstDocSnap.id).limitToLast(n) results in the __name__ only indexes are not supported. This implies there is a implicit ascending index behind the scenes but not a descending one by default? Why not both?

Comment: This answer is outdated, as you can do this now.

Comment: Not for me, like @AndyFusniak explained, endBefore(firstDocSnap.id).limitToLast(n).orderBy() still doesn't work. Doug's workaround seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird work-around, but it is possible to sort on document ID descending if you have additional `where` conditions. This is PHP. I have only tested this with equality conditions.

So, even though this doesn't work (failing with a create index link that leads to the error "__name__ only indexes are not supported"):

```
$docs = $fsClient
    ->collection('incidents')
    ->orderBy(FieldPath::documentId(), 'DESC')
    ->documents();
```

This does:

```
$docs = $fsClient
    ->collection('incidents')
    ->orderBy(FieldPath::documentId(), 'DESC')
    ->where('dummy-field', '=', true)
    ->documents();
```

This does require you to add a `dummy-field` with a value of `true` to all your documents.

Comment: EDIT: This does not appear to actually sort in descending order

Comment: @forresthopkinsa I just double-checked, and this does work for me. If you have time, I would be interested to see an example where this technique does not result in results being sorted in descending order.

Comment: Are you using automatic or manual document IDs?

Comment: My use case was that the document IDs were numbers (as strings, of course), so: "1001", "1002", "1003"... and when I requested them in descending order using this technique, they returned in *ascending* order, which happens to also be insertion order