# How to get the previous document in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to navigate through the next and previous post of my firestore collection. I have setup next post function. But I can't make the previous function.

Here is my next post query:

```
firestore()
      .collection('Posts')
      .orderBy(firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
      .startAfter(this.state.currentDoc)
      .limit(1)
```

But sadly, firestore doesn't work with `.orderBy(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'desc')`
I tried with:

```
firestore()
      .collection('Posts')
      .orderBy(firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
      .limit(1)
```

It goes to the very first document of the collection. Adding ascending order doesn't work here again.

Let me know if any further information is needed.

***EDIT:***

According to the answer, here is what I am trying, instead of id, I am using time of the post when it was created. The time format is like: `1625511322000`

```
firestore()
      .collection('Posts')
      .orderBy('time', 'desc')
      .startAfter(this.state.currentDoc)
      .limit(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.startAfter()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#add_a_simple_cursor_to_a_query) method should do it in descending order as well.

```
firestore()
      .collection('Posts')
      .orderBy("docID", "desc")
      .startAfter(this.state.currentDoc)
      .limit(1)
```

Let's say you have 4 documents: Doc1, Doc2, Doc3 and Doc4.

In first case, passing Doc2 in `startAfter` will return Doc3. (assuming the DocIDs are in ascending order).
Similarly to get the previous post, you can sort the list in descending order and use `startAfter` which should return `Doc1`.

However, it seems you cannot sort documents in descending order using the document ID as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119208/how-to-get-documents-descending-by-documentid). So you would have to store the document ID in the document as a field and then sort it like this:

```
.orderBy("docID", "desc")
```

If you try sorting in descending order using the document ID, you'll end up getting an error prompting you to create an index but you can't create it. The Firestore console will return an error, *"**name** only indexes are not supported"*

Comment: Are you suggesting to add an extra field docID? Or that's something built in for firestore?

Comment: @Abrar yes add it yourself and set it as the document ID's value. You will have to do that to order docs in descending order.

Comment: I am trying to use time, but it doesn't work. It just jumps to the first record

Comment: @Abrar what 'time'? Please share screenshot of your document and your updated code.

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look at it now

Comment: @Abrar just to clarify as per your updated code your documents will be sorted on the basis of time and not document ID or name. Also make sure the field name is correct. If you want to sort on the basis of time then make sure you use the time field in both ascending and descending queries.

Comment: The field name is fine and working when I sort it without `startAfter` and `limit`. It sorts all the data fine 